# Como montar menu e sub menu?

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Como mostrar um sub-menu dentro de outro?

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Usuários", "Index", "Usuarios")</li>
      <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logs", "Logs", "Usuarios")</li>
      </ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
  </div>
```

A ideia é que o Link *Logs* do **Usuário** fique logo abaixo do link de usuário e assim que o usuário passar o mouse sobre link **Usuários** seja mostrado o link *Logs*.

Comment: Tentou alguma coisa? Você pode usar o evento mouseover do Jquery: https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, isso não tem ligação direta com [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). O que você quer é apenas um sub menu com Bootstrap.

Ficaria algo assim:

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}

.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top marginBottom-0" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">App Nome</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuários <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Log's</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="page-header">Bootstrap 3.0.3<br>
            <small>Navbar - Click Dropdown - Sub - Sub - Sub - Sub ...</small></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
        
            <div class="row">
               <h1>You Like It ?</h1>
               <br>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Neste exemplo possui mais alguns sub-menus para você ter ideia de níveis de menus.

Créditos: [bootply/yahyaerturan.](http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz)